# Async render react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await

I've got a qr code scanner and based on the response from the server, i want to show a modal with different back colors!

I used `react-native-qrcode-scanner` and `react-native-modalbox`.

**App.js:**

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header headerText="Scan " />

        <View style={styles.cameraContainer}>
          <QRCodeScanner
            ref={node => {
              this.scanner = node;
            }}
            onRead={this.onRead.bind(this)}
            cameraStyle={{ height: "100%" }}
          />
        </View>

        {this.renderModal()}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

And then we have the **onRead()** function which is:

```
onRead(e) {
    // send request to server and receive the response!
    switch (msg from server){
      case "IN": {
        userStatus = "1";
      }

      case "OUT": {
        userStatus = "0";
      }

      case "Error": {
        userStatus = "-1";
      }

    this.refs.myModal.open();
}
```

and finally the **renderModal()**:

```
renderModal() {
    switch (userStatus) {
      case "1": {
        (modalBackgroundColor = "#90EE90"), (modalText = "In");
      }

      case "0": {
        (modalBackgroundColor = "#87CEFA"), (modalText = "Out");
      }

      case "-1": {
        (modalBackgroundColor = "#FF0000"), (modalText = "Error");
      }
    }

    return (
      <Modal
        style={styles.modalStyle}
        position={"center"}
        ref={"myModal"}
        backdropColor={modalBackgroundColor}
        onClosed={() => {
          this.scanner.reactivate();
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.text}>{modalText}</Text>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
```

The problem is my `onRead()` is an async function but the `renderModal()` in rendered before i receive the response!
Any solution?

> Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general thing with Async Functions, the way I go about this in regards to rendering, is to save in your local State an IsLoading: True, and the result of your Functions then changing that to IsLoading: False, and only when that IsLoading is set to False, do rendering, and while it is set to True, display some placeholder that communicates to the user that the data is being processed.

This gives feedback back to the user, and make it responsive.

EDIT:

```
isLoading(isLoading = true){
this.setState({isLoading})
}

{this.state.isLoading ? <div>placeholder</div> : this.renderModal()}
```

and inside the return of your async function run
isLoading(false)
and when you initiate the actual read, run
isLoading(true).

Comment: it's not a general purpose app! i just want to scan a qr code and change the back depends on the response from the server!

Comment: I am saying this as a general thing, you can apply it to scanning a QR code aswell. You can change the back to a placeholder while you wait for the server to respond.

Comment: I am sorry, then I don't understand your problem. I am trying to help.
Your "{this.renderModal()}" is getting rendered right away, which takes in the data from your QR scanner and renders it, however your QR Scanner has to still wait for an answer as it's Async. Therefore if I understand correct, you have to make it render some placeholder type of content, and on the end of your OnRead function, communicate that the read is complete and then update your local state with that datum, to cancel out the placeholder values and send it proper data.

Comment: Alright. I edited my original post, to include what I think. If you don't like it, trash it, if it gives you some inspiration, great.